# How to replicate this texture effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, effects

I want to express this texture but I do not know how. I think I used a Photoshop filter. I tried using noise and spray brushes with no success.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are one of the images your work or are they both references?

Answer (score 2):

The Noise filter looks like it could do it, but it looks like you could replicate it better with the Grain Effect.

You can make a linear gradient map with the color stops set to your palette and go to

> Effect > Texture > Grain

Try the default settings or play around with them if you want a different effect.

You can alternatively use a black and white gradient with the Grain Effect applied set to a blend mode of multiply above a fill color layer.

There's a good tutorial with more detailed explanations here: http://vectips.com/tutorials/create-grainy-textures/

Answer (score 2):

You can try using this technique posted here:

[Gradient effect with dots](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/70334/gradient-effect-with-dots)

To simply put it:

1. Create monochrome gradient version of path
2. Effect > Sketch > Graphic Pen
3. Effect > Document Raster Effect Settings > Set reso to 300, check AA and mask
4. Add the colored path on top then play around with blending modes

*Tried to add a subtle gaussian blur to slightly smoothen the grain

Answer (score 0):

In addition to creating the texture yourself using tools found in Illustrator it is also a common practice to find high quality stock images of textures and use transparency to create effects like this, or to vectorize the image to create reusable patterns and textures.

For example, Blog Spoon Graphics has [free vector texture packs](https://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/freebies/free-vector-texture-pack-for-adobe-illustrator) made from stock images. Creative Bloq also has a [great tutorial](http://www.creativebloq.com/graphic-design/add-depth-and-texture-illustrator-5132626) on making your own textures.